# Tiger aloe, is developing brown spots and is browning

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, aloe

So i have had this tiger aloe for almost a year now. it always seemed fine. but recently it has developed dry spots, and the inside of the plant is browning (see picture). I water it once a month by placing the plant in 15 cm of water for 20 minutes. It is also on my windowsill and the sun goes down on my side of the room, so lots of afternoon sun.

[image]